# Xamarin - Android app cant access site anymore

Tags: android, html, xamarin

I've made an app that calls a website to populate its content... it worked without problems, but suddenly today I noticed that the app is not getting data from the site anymore. On all installations of the app. How is this possible? Has my site been added to some sort of blacklist for whatever reason by google?

EDIT:

if I open Url in the browser i see "1".. but this returns "":

```
     downloadString = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(URL);
```

also SSL checker on the URL reports a expired certificate, but the dates seem to be ok:

```
   Common name: gallery-share.com
SANs: gallery-share.com, autodiscover.gallery-share.com, cpanel.gallery- 
share.com, cpcalendars.gallery-share.com, cpcontacts.gallery-share.com, 
mail.gallery-share.com, webdisk.gallery-share.com, webmail.gallery-share.com, 
whm.gallery-share.com, www.gallery-share.com
Valid from March 30, 2020 to June 29, 2020
Serial Number: 92d96e0255980f1ae39d34d0c11576ef
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
```

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=gallery-share.com

Comment: uhm, not sure I understand.. why would my site blocking me?

Comment: @SushiHangover I see that my site has one expired certificate. (there is the message there, but all certificates seem to be fine...) COULD that be the cause? that the app does not diplay sites that have a expired certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the ssl certificates was expired.. Renewing the certificate on the site sovled the problem.

Comment: You can mark this answer which would help more people with same problem:).